# Publishing funding issues and collaboration after PhD graduation

Tags: publications, journals, funding, conference, collaboration

I managed to graduate out of a PhD program in Computer Science. But I had horrible experience with my former advisor. In addition to my dissertation related research works, I had some ideas and preliminary results with unfinished writeups. I'm now working in industry and have some free time after work and I want to continue working on them. Absolutely don't want to work with my former advisor again. I know there are significant fees to publish on a ACM/IEEE conference, e.g., registration, publishing, travelling, etc. While I cannot afford this due to financial reasons and my current employer won't support this. I've thought about two ways:

1. Try to find professors/researchers in other universities/institutes in my direction and collaborate with them. If the work gets accepted from a conference, is it possible to seek financial assistance from them? Are they willing to pay the fees out of their fundings to support this (assuming I'm the first author)?
2. Try to publish it to journals (I never published anything on journals), do ACM/IEEE journals have lesser fees? Do they have other means of supports for folks in industry?
   Any other suggestions?

Comment: Seems more likely that a university partner would expect someone employed in industry to support their own travel.

Comment: @JonCuster hmm... Maybe finding an industry lab to collaborate is a better idea?

Comment: Universities could potentially support it.  It depends on the relationship.  I have PI who routinely asks me to pay for travel for all sorts of people.  But this PI does it based on relationships to these people -- they are never strangers.

Comment: @yourfriendlyresearchadmin Sounds reasonable if they established relationships. Your experience and comment give me hope :)

Answer (score 1):

[ACM does not charge fees](https://www.acm.org/publications/authors/submissions) to publish in their journals other than Open Access, which does require funding from authors.

I doubt that other academic contributors can contribute to your attending conferences, but they can probably cover their own participation if you are willing to have them as presenters. I see no problem with this myself and have often deferred to others.

For some, but not likely for you, conferences will defer fees. This is mostly for students and for those at small, non research, institutions not able to pay. But travel and accommodation still needs too be covered unless, just by luck, a conference is near you.

Conferences are, however, the main venue for CS publication.

The IEEE policies are similar to those of ACM, also.

Comment: Maybe journal first paper and then go to a conference could be a better idea?